# How to increase the font size in Azure Dashboard?

Tags: azure

I am working on creating dashboard in Azure using Log Analytics Workspace query to show a value in dashboard. But the size of font for the value is small. Please help me with increasing the size of font.

Also is the changing of color of value is supported if a certain threshold value is breached?

Answer (score 0):

> How to increase the font size in Azure Dashboard?

You can increase the size of the tile in Azure dashboard as shown in below Screenshot:

- click and drag the icon which is shown below to resize any tile on your azure dashboard.

[image]

Refer this Microsoft [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/new-analytics-features-for-dashboards/) to resize and edit query.